# Target specific row in SQLite (Cordova)

Tags: javascript, sqlite, cordova, phonegap

Please help. I'm looping through rows and display the items in a list. When I click a row, I need to get the row `name`. I think I need to get the `rowid` but I'm not sure how. All the below code is getting is the last row `name`.

```
db.transaction(function(tx) {
    tx.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS client (name TEXT)');
    tx.executeSql('SELECT * FROM client', [], function (tx, results) {
        for(var x = 0; x < results.rows.length; x++) {
            var $single = results.rows.item(x);
            var $singleName = $single.name;
            var $wrapper = $('<div class="client-row" />').appendTo('.client-list');
            $wrapper.append ('<div class="client-name">' + $singleName + '</div>');

            $(document).on("click", ".client-row", function(){
                $(".indiv-client").show();
                $(".current-client").text($singleName);
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your on function is defining the behaviour of every element with `class="client-row"` Therefore when you run it in the loop like this it will set every client row element to be `$singleName`

simply create the div as

```
'<div class="item" data-name="' + $singleName +'" />'
```

and then use `.attr('data-name');` to retrieve it (oh and set the `.on` behaviour outside of the loop)

Comment: Didn't even think of this. Thanks you mate :)